# Eclipse for PHP - What's this icon?

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I am using Eclipse for PHP development in the Remote Systems Explorer perspective.

I noticed a different icon appearing for only few files in the project explorer window.

[image]

Notice the icon for logout.php file which is unlike a regular php file icon like for network_setup.php.

When opened, the icons on the tabs are same though.

[image]

Anyone has any clue about this?

Comment: Does it open like a regular PHP file?

Comment: Yes, it does. Also, when I open the files, they have a regular PHP icon on the tabs. Not this new icon.

Comment: I think that's an overlay signalling some status, e.g. changed, changing, binary transfer, whatever - have never seen it but I don't use that perspective so this does not mean much.

Comment: @Coding Freak: Well, I really expected someone to say this. Why would I not accept an answer which really answers my question? You give the right answer and I would accept. I have asked only less than 10 question by far only few got sensible answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that the file is marked as an executable file by your operating system?

Comment: Great catch. They do have different file permissions set. This could be a cause.

Comment: You should probably not keep your PHP files executable, btw :)

Comment: @dev_musings Oh, excellent question, I don't have a good answer. I think it is best practice to only use it for files that should be executed directly, and since PHP is interpreted, execution would never be necessary.